# S5 unable to add additional homescreen

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-5, home-screen

I'm trying to learn how to add an additional homescreen.  According to docs I should be able to slide over to the right most screen, long press, and a 'ghost' homescreen with a big + sign would appear-- clicking that would add extra homescreens.

The problem is that the homescreen with the plus sign is not appearing when I long press on the right most (or even left most) existing homescreen.

Is there another way to get additional homescreens installed?  This phone was previously installed with Cyanogen & Fusion.

Comment: What launcher are you using?  What ROM are you using?

Comment: I figured it out, just have to hold & drag an app icon to the far right.. a new homescreen auto loads.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Lollipop, so to add a new blank homescreen I needed to hold and drag a program icon to the far right.. a new homescreen automatically appears.